# Promotion Management - Error - Unable to retrieve the root LCM folder

Tags: business-objects

If I go to CMC and select Promotion Management I get the following error
**Sorry, Promotion management application is unable to process your request.
The error from the server is: Unable to retrieve the root LCM folder. Please check if you have sufficient rights to perform promotion management.**

The original LCM and Promotion Jobs folders were deleted. I have re-created them, but this is probably useless because the new folders will have a new CUID.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: What does you list of servers look like in CMC? Do you have a dedicated Promotion Management server?

Comment: Hi Isaac, sorry about the delay.

No there is not a Promotion Management server in the server list.

Comment: You could try removing the Promotion Management services from whatever server there are in (likely the AdaptiveProcessingServer) and then create a new Promotion Management server containing those services. I would caution you that this is significant change about which I would recommend you contact SAP Support.